# How to count the number of words per line in a text file in C

Tags: c

I want to be able to read a file line by line and count how many words are in each line. This is what I have so far:

```
int countWords(char* filename)
{
   int wordCount=0;
   int lineCount=0;

   FILE *ptr_file;
   char buf[1000];
   ptr_file = fopen(filename,"r");

   if (!ptr_file) {
     return 1;
   }

   while (fgets(buf,1000,ptr_file) != NULL) {
     int len = strlen(buf);
     for(int x=0; x<len; x++) {
       if (buf[x]!=' ' && buf[x+1]==' '){
         wordCount++;
       }
       else if (buf[x]=='\n') {
         lineCount++;
         printf("Line %d: %d words", lineCount, wordCount);
         wordCount=0;
       }
       printf("%d",wordCount);
     }

   }

   fclose(ptr_file);

   return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty new at C so still getting used to the whole pointer thing. When I run this program I get no output. This is the sort of output I'm looking for:

```
Line 1: 3 words
Line 2: 5 words
...
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the help on providing a minimum _complete_ verifiable example. This isn't a runnable program. The behavior is consistent with failure to open the input file, for example. Yet you haven't shown enough to say if that's the problem.

Comment: There are many problems with this, most of the same problems are also in q74's reply.  A couple of hints: 1) Update your post with a complete example, and make sure it compiles and runs.  For starters, it should have a `main()`.  2) Consider breaking your code out into separate functions (instead of running everything altogether).  3) Consider `#define 1000`, instead of hard-coding "1000" different places.  4) Consider [perror()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/perror) to print out the cause behind any errors. 5) Do multiple consecutive spaces mean "multiple words"?  Does a tab mean "not a word"?

Answer (score -1):

Please compile the following code using GCC (gcc test.c -o test):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

    main() {
       int wordCount=0;
       int lineCount=0;

       FILE *ptr_file;
       char buf[1000];
       ptr_file = fopen("test.txt", "r");

       if (!ptr_file) {
         return 1;
       }

       while (fgets(buf,1000,ptr_file) != NULL) {
         int len = strlen(buf);
         int x;
         for(x=0; x<len; x++) {
           if (buf[x+1]==' '){
             wordCount++;
           }else if (buf[x]=='\n') {
             lineCount++;
             wordCount++;
             printf("Line %i: %i words\n", lineCount, wordCount);
             wordCount=0;
           }
         }

       }

       fclose(ptr_file);

       return 0;
}
```

test.txt file:

```
word1 word2 word3 word4
word1 word2
word1
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5
```

output:

```
Line 1: 4 words
Line 2: 2 words
Line 3: 1 words
Line 4: 5 words
Line 5: 1 words
```

you need to handle the last line in your code of course